# Updating an array and converting from varchar to integer

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm updating an array by adding a varchar to an int4 array. The 'varchar' field is all numbers so I tried casting it to ::integer but it isn't working

```
update dwh.attr_lookup set kli_tree = array[target_909_kli::integer] || kli_tree
```

is giving me this error

```
ERROR: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""

Query = update
dwh.attr_lookup set kli_tree = array[target_909_kli::integer]
|| kli_tree
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to cast an empty string to an integer and that doesn't work:

```
=> select ''::int;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
LINE 1: select ''::int;
               ^
```

You'll have to decide what you want to do with empty strings. If you want to convert them to zeros, then something like this should work:

```
array[case when target_909_kli = '' then 0 else target_909_kli::integer end]
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously your `varchar` field is *not* all numbers. There would not be any double quotes in this case - as the error message informs us.

Try giving a full example if the error has not clear by now. Including table definition and sample values.

Comment: Actually it means that the OP is trying to cast an empty string, not a string with double quotes.